# Convert CAD to raster

Tags: printing, vector-graphics, cad, raster-graphics

How do printers convert the vectorial CAD graphics to dots in paper? I have a 50mmx50mm with 4095x4095 points "printing" system and I'd like to print some CAD files to it? Should I use the existing printing system? Or convert the CAD file to something my "printer" undertands and if so, how?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All printers understand postscript - in fact, most software that can print outputs to a postscript file and feeds it to the printer driver.

Export it as a postscript and edit it with The Gimp if you think something is wrong. Then print it out.

Comment: "All printers" = Upper end laser printers. Your desktop inkjet does not understand PostScript, and lower end printers may only implement a subset. However, GhostScript is quite capable as a rasterizer.

Comment: I disagree - several cheap inkjets use postscript or variation thereof to print from. Older ones typically used PCL or some proprietary language.